# Facebook fb:activity tab fails to refresh

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have a facebook XFBML activity tab, using the usual `<fb:activity ...></fb:activity>`; the code comes straight from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/.

If the user is logged into facebook when the page is loaded, it works fine.

If the user is not logged in initially, the box is blank (fair enough). When he presses the login button on my page to log into facebook and sign up for my app, I attempt to refresh the activity plugin using the function:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

(see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

After 30 seconds, however, this fails, leaving the activity box blank and giving the following error on the console:

```
1 XFBML tags failed to render in 30000ms
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?